# How to define a custom autocomplete hints in codemirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to use codeMirror in my project that uses a new language, and to test it i need an editor with autocomplete feature, appearantly codeMirror will do the job but i need to define a hints DB for the new language like "ruban,image...".
So i want to know to build a custom hint function.
Cordially.

Comment: show your current code please

Comment: i don't have an autoComplete codeyet, but i included the API as explained in codeMirror documentation